# Why no Atom in Stack Overflow Trends?

Tags: support, trends

Try this:

- Go here: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=
- Type `sublimetext` in the "tags" box. Notice how it autocompletes and gives you a graph.
- Type `vscode` in the "tags" box. Notice how it autocompletes and gives you a graph.
- Now try typing `atom` in the "tags" box. Notice how it neither autocompletes nor gives you any graph.

How can I get a Sublime-vs-Atom-vs-Visual Studio Code graph in Stack Overflow Trends?

Comment: Assuming they are tags on the main Q&A site, it should be [tag:atom-editor].

Comment: @Gimby just checked even [tag:atom-editor] does not work. https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=atom-editor

Comment: It needs to be a valid tag, so not [atom].  And it needs enough questions to generate reliable data.  So not [atom-editor] either, it is 48 questions shy of reaching that goal. Try again in a month or two :)